# Put all code in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, raty

Here I have an example of how to create a 'side_bar' with javascript when I click on marker

```
var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers["+parseInt(gmarkers.length-1)+"],\"click\");'>"+place.name+"</a><br>"+ $('<div>').raty({ score: place.rating, path: 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img' }) +"</br>";
    document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;
}
```

*''raty is jquery plugin for visualise rating with stars''*

but this code give me this results:

```
    Name of place
    [object Object]
... ...
```

How I can put this code in function to work it correctly?

Is any way to do this?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "put this code in function". Put in what function? Do you wish to create a function for your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating a jQuery wrapper to a string, that is the reason

*without changing much from your code*

```
var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[" + parseInt(gmarkers.length - 1) + "],\"click\");'>" + place.name + "</a><br>" + '<div class="raty" />' + "</br>";

$(side_bar_html).appendTo('#side_bar').filter('.raty').raty({
    score : place.rating,
    path : 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img'
})
```

Comment: all is ok, but look here http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/76, rating show and after seconds just disapere. What is going on? I dont get it!

Comment: @MarcoJordan there is a recursive call to `findPlaces()` which seems to be the reason. `            if (++searchIndex < boxes.length) 
                setTimeout(function(){
                  findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex);
                },300);`

Comment: so how I can fix that? is any way?